# Why is there an error in the following java code?

Tags: java

I can't figure out the problem in this.

```
    public class Trying {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         new Trying().go("hi", 1);
         new Trying().go("hi", "world", 2);
      }
     public void go(String... y, int x) {
         System.out.print(y[y.length - 1] + " ");
      }
    }
```

Comment: Show the stacktrace, please.

Comment: How about providing us with the error.

Comment: See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161912/why-varargs-should-be-the-last-in-method-signature

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A *varargs* argument, like `String... y` has to be the last variable in a method declaration. Change your declaration to:

```
public void go(int x, String... y) {
```

Comment: Oh. Thanks. Pretty stupid mistake, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

There is an attempt to  declare Regular parameter after the varargs parameter which is illegal.

```
public void go(String... y, int x) //Error
```

Restriction of varags:

> 1. varargs must be declared last
>
> 2.There must be only one varargs parameter

change your method to  `public void go(int x, String... y)`

Answer (score 1):

A [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) argument must be the last variable in a method declaration

```
public class Trying {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Trying().go(1,"hi");
        new Trying().go(2,"hi", "world");
    }
    public void go(int x,String... y) {
        for(int i=0;i<x;i++){
            System.out.println(y[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

For [More](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161912/why-varargs-should-be-the-last-in-method-signature)