# Scala Method Parameters - Combining variable arguments and default parameters

Tags: scala, methods

Is it possible to combine variable arguments and default parameters in a Scala method function definition? Specifically, I'm trying to write a patch method with the following signature:

```
def patch(body: String, contentType: ContentType = ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON, customHeaders: (String, String)*)
```

I get the error `Parameter section with *-parameter cannot have default arguments`. So I assume it was a matter of ordering the parameters. However, I'm required to place *-parameters last.

My questions are:

- Why does *-parameter have to be last? Is it so the compiler can easily parse the arguments?
- Why can't *-parameter come after the default arguments? I imagine the same argument applies where it's easier for the compiler to parse arguments because default arguments and variable arguments are both optional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does *-parameter have to be last?

Technically, even if the *-parameter isn't restricted to be the last, the compiler should be able to figure it out.  This [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161912/why-varargs-should-be-the-last-in-method-signature) offers some insight (albeit unofficial) into possible rationale.

> Why can't *-parameter come after the default arguments?

If *-parameter after a default argument were allowed, there would be ambiguity in which argument variables should be assigned the supplied parameters in some cases.  For example:

```
def foo(a: String = "hi", bs: String*) = a + " " + bs.mkString(" ")

foo("hello", "world")  // Should "hello" go to `a` or be a part of `bs`?
```

Note that technically this restriction could also be lifted, say, by requiring explicit argument variable assignment in cases when ambiguity arises (e.g. `foo(a="hello", "world")`).

To circumvent the restriction, you can resort to currying (which allows you to have a *-parameter per argument list):

```
def bar(s: String, i: Int = 1, ts: (String, String)*) =
  ts.map(t => (t._1 + s*i, t._1 + s*i))
// <console>:23: error: a parameter section with a `*'-parameter is not allowed to have default arguments
//        def bar(s: String, i: Int = 1, ts: (String, String)*) = {

def bar(s: String, i: Int = 1)(ts: (String, String)*) =
  ts.map(t => (t._1 + s*i, t._2 + s*i))

bar("!", 2)(("a", "b"), ("c", "d"))
// res1: Seq[(String, String)] = ArrayBuffer((a!!,b!!), (c!!,d!!))
```

Comment: "If *-parameter after a default argument were allowed, there would be ambiguity in which argument variables should be assigned the supplied parameters in some cases." – Not really. It is pretty simple to come up with easy-to-understand rules to disambiguate. It is simply a design choice.

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag, I think you're right.  Among other reasons, the design choice could be based on that the decision of "*-parameter must be the last" was made and the fact that default arguments are more practically useful to be placed last.  I've added a relevant note in the answer.